# Clean up after creating the pdf

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf, html2pdf

I'm generating a pdf file with html2fpdf.

```
$pdf = new HTML2FPDF();
$pdf->HTML2FPDF("P","mm","A4");
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->output('sample.pdf');
```

This sample works great. But:

How do I delete the pdf after the output? I just want to have links in my tool, the users can download the pdf and after that it shoud be deleted on the server.

How can I 'clean up' after generating the pdf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP's file deletion function called `unlink()`

Call this function with the full path to the generated PDF file (or any file for that matter) and PHP will delete that file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

---

You don't necessarily have to delete the file immediately after the user has downloaded it.  You can just as easily place all the generated files in one central folder and have a cron job execute a more general clean up script simply removing the older files.

One method could be -

- Scan the contents of the folder using [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php).
- Iterate over its files in a `foreach` loop..
- Inspect the creation time of each file using [`filemtime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).
- If the creation time was over hour ago, delete the file using [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

---

Because you are generating the PDF file yourself within *your* PHP code, I didn't mention the permissions consideration.  Here would be a good place to mention that your PHP must have the correct file system permissions in order to perform any action on the file system.  You are creating a PDF file so it's safe to assume that you have the correct permissions to make changes to the file system but if you plan on using this `unlink()` function in other scripts make sure that the files you are dealing with have the correct permissions set.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't add the 'F' flag to the output function there will be no pdf files stored on the server at all:

```
$pdf->output('sample.pdf', 'F'); //stores PDF on server
```

In your case the script itself behaves like an actual pdf file. So, creating a link to the script is just like a link to the pdf, except that the PDF is created every time the script is requested. To tell the browser it's a PDF the `content-type` response header must be set to `application/pdf`:

```
content-type: application/pdf
```

This way the broser knows that it's a pdf even if the URL is ending in a `.php`. You can use rewrite engine to make it end in pdf or whatever else.

Sending the headers is done by the fpdf/tcpdf. In short: you don't have to do any cleanup, because no pdf file is stored on the server.

If you wonder what the name is for than, try saving the pdf file. The recommanded name when saving will be sample.pdf.

**Reference**:

- PHP [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function, at the examples there is one for sending pdf
- [FPDF::Output()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm)
- [TCPDF::Output()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a3d6dcb62298ec9d42e9125ee2f5b23a1)